# Why I can't get hamburger menu to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help here. I'm trying to make a hamburger menu for my website but for some reason which I can't figure out, it doesn't work. Here's the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code which I've written in codepen.io:
https://codepen.io/TheUnrealisticProgrammer/pen/QvjvVW

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('Menu').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('Trigger');
   });
   });
```

From the code, the first span bar should animate by rotating 135 degrees after I click on it but it's not.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error? Also, you need to post the relevant code here, not in a Pen.

Comment: Typically one needs to load jQuery *before* attempting to use it...

Comment: Your Code Pen is complaining about `$` not being defined. Have you linked to `jQuery` yet?

Comment: After I added jQuery to the pen, I noticed that you reference `'Menu'`, it should be `'#Menu'`.

Comment: Actually I am pretty new to codepen, so I thought that jquery is already loaded in codepen by default and ready to use, so I was concentrating on finding the error, and while experimenting with css and javascript, I broke it accidently like for example the missing '#' while selecting the menu div.

Comment: But with the help of Bhupendra Singh's answer, I fixed the issue with codepen by adding jquery reference in codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your css style is broken,
2. you don't have jQuery (add through setting)
3. `$('Menu')` this is jQuery as other said, you are selecting id so should be `$('#Menu')`

check this link for working example, fixed jQuery, js and CSS:

https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/wdKZVj

fixed css:

```
#Menu{
  position:relative;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:50px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

#Menu span{
  position:absolute;
  background:orange;
  display:block;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius:50px;  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#Menu span:nth-child(1){
  top:0px;
}
#Menu span:nth-child(2){
  top:18px;
}
#Menu span:nth-child(3){
  top:36px;
}

#Menu.Trigger span:nth-child(1){
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#Menu.Trigger span:nth-child(2){
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

#Menu.Trigger span:nth-child(3){
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Nice one. But may I know, the meaning of content=""; as you've written there in your css?

Comment: @Arko991 oh my bad, pasted the wrong code. check the updated one now

Comment: @Arko991 I just checked your code pen, seems like you updated a bit. I found this css `#Menu.Trigger span:nth-child(3){ top: 25px; ...` change it to `18px` and it is perfect =D

Comment: ah, now your code makes sense! And yes I know I made top:25px as that cross sign kinda looks cool. :D

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery and JQuery UI before using. And `$('Menu')` Menu is not a tag but it is ID of div as per your Code Pen. It has to be `$('#Menu')`.

Answer (score 1):

Please do these steps.

1. Go to your code pen
2. Click on the setting icon available in the JS section.
3. Add jquery reference (**https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js**) by clicking on the add another resource button placed at the right bottom of the dialog box.
4. In your javascript, you are using $('Menu'). which is actually searching for the tag called Menu. Change it to $('#Menu'). As you want to target to the ID.
5. It will work perfectly fine.